# Trim a string to a specific number of characters in R

Tags: r, string, substring

I would like to trim a character vector to the first five characters in each element.  In this example I would like to trim each number in string to the first five characters.  I am sure there must be an easy way to do this.

```
string<-
c("3243423",
"23423",
"34243234",
"2342",
"32544532",
"85678657")
```

I would like to have a a vector

```
c("32434",
"23423",
"34243",
"2342",
"32544",
"85678")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.  Hope this is helpful.

`strtrim(string, 5)`

Answer (score 9):

The following works as well (didn't know about `strtrim`)

```
substring(string, 1, 5)
```

Comment: @MatthewR I appreciate the check but in my opinion your answer was better for this circumstance.  Please feel free to move the check there if this is the case so future searchers will see this as the best choice.

Answer (score 4):

`stri_sub` function from `stringi` package

```
stri_sub("123456789",1,4)
## [1] "1234"
```